# How do I convert only the column names from vertical to horizontal

Tags: php, sql

This simple code below outputs all 75 column names only, to a vertical output. I need it to be a horizontal output with a . in between each column name. All the code I try is far to complex in syntax for me to do this as it is written for the column contents and names. I know someone can solve this in 30 seconds.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","voxeo_sql");
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM CNETELIG_MEMELIG";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){      
echo $row['Field']."<br>";  
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you replace the `<br>` with a `.` ?

Comment: add your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace

```
 echo $row['Field']."<br>";
```

with:

```
 echo $row['Field'].".";
```

Comment: I knew someone would help. Thank you very much!